# Why did installing VS break Python scripts from running at Command Prompt?

Tags: python, visual-studio

I'm using Python 3.7. I've installed a few packages using `pip install`. I usually run the scripts I've written directly from the command line, in the Windows Command Prompt.

The other day I installed Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition, mainly for coding C++ console apps. While installing, I noticed it has support for Python, so I checked the box to include the Python features of Visual Studio. I've done nothing further with respect to configuring VS.

Now, when I try to run my Python scripts from the command line, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`. For example:

```
C:\Users\me\Python\MyScript.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\Python\MyScript.py", line 25, in <module>
    import pyvisa.errors
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyvisa'
```

Here are the `import` statements at the top of my script:

```
# System imports
import sys
import os
import re
import argparse
from enum import Enum

# Third-party library imports
import pyvisa.errors
import pyvisa as visa
```

The library in question is still installed:

```
C:\Users\me\Python>pip show pyvisa
Name: PyVISA
Version: 1.10.1
Summary: Python VISA bindings for GPIB, RS232, TCPIP and USB instruments
Home-page: https://github.com/pyvisa/pyvisa
Author: Torsten Bronger, Gregor Thalhammer
Author-email: bronger@physik.rwth-aachen.de
License: MIT License
Location: c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

My path and PYTHONPATH are:

```
Path=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;

PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\me\Python\pkg
```

Here is the `sys.path`:

```
    C:\Users\me\Python>python -m site
sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\me\\Python',
    'C:\\Users\\me\\Python\\pkg',
    'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
    'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib',
    'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32',
    'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages',
    'C:\\Users\\me\\Python\\common',
    'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
    'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
    'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-p`enter code here`ackages\\Pythonwin',
]
USER_BASE: 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

I've read several of the top Google hits for `ModuleNotFoundError`, but a simple explanation is not to be found.

What is a straightforward solution to this?

Comment: check `sys.executable` from VS. It's probably different from the executable/installation where you installed pyvisa;

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You're right. VS is using the 64-bit version of Python, while my command-line installation is using the 32-bit version. If I type `python MyScript.py` instead of just `MyScript.py` it works.

Comment: classical problem. Now install pyvisa on your 64 bit install and you can use it through VS. Or get rid of the 32 bit version if you don't need it. The lesser the better.